# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes

Tags: java, class, jboss, jersey, wildfly

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes

Facing above issue after upgrading wildfly from 8.2 to 15.0.1

Dependencies in my project are as follows.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

where jersey.version = 1.11.
Please help to resolve this....

Comment: Are you including Jersey in your deployment or installing it? By default WildFly uses RESeasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: I have used the jersey dependency in pom only ..

Comment: I think you either have to install Jersey as a module and/or exclude the `jaxrs` subsystem from your deployment. If you're just using the JAX-RS API then you don't need to provide Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

Try jersey version **1.19.1**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
```